# Centering Text over Image

Tags: html, css, image, text

Here's my summarized code

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
      <div>
      <img src="Pictures/titlepic.jpg" width="1035" height="200">
      <h1 class="text_over_image">Welcome to my Sandbox</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width: 1060px;
    margin: auto;
    }
.text_over_image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    }
```

I've tried `left: 50%`, `text-align:center`, any number of things with no great luck.  I didn't want to do a `left: 50px` (or whatever the value needs to be) as whats unseen is that the length of the text changes depending on Javascript values.  So the title could be short, or long and I want it to center no matter what.

Ideas?

Comment: you need to put image in background of your div

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following css:

```
.text_over_image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
 }
```

===Edit ===

```
.wrap {
    width: 1060px;
    height:auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.text_over_image {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    height:100px;
}
```

There you go [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuyWT/)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't have the effect you were probably thinking: http://d.pr/i/huk4

Comment: @ChaseWestlye hmmm 2 min let me tinker.

Answer (score 4):

```css
div.counter {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.counter span {
    position: absolute;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div.counter span:before {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 100%;
   content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
    <span>TEXT</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
      <div>
       <h1 class="text_over_image">Welcome to my Sandbox</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap
{
background-image:url(Pictures/titlepic.jpg);
width:1035px;
height:200px;
}
.text_over_image
{
text-align:center;
line-height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I think you nailed it...  Text is centered but the background image no longer appears:
CSS: http://d.pr/i/7hMZ
HTML: http://d.pr/i/dzeK
Render: http://d.pr/i/bCBR

Ideas?

Comment: The height is dynamic, line height 200px won't result in a centered text.